# Exact sequences and finitely generated projective modules

Tags: modules, projective-module

Let $R$ be a ring and $A,B,C$ be $R$-modules in an exact sequence

$$0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow 0.$$

Submodules or quotients of **finitely generated projective** modules are not necesserarily finitely generated and projective.

However, I was wondering if any assertion of the type "$A$ and $B$ are f.g. projective implies that $C$ is f.g. projective" is true (up to permutation of the names) ?

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample: $R=A=B=\mathbb Z$, and the map from $A$ to $B$ is multiplication by 2.  Then $C=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is not projective.

Answer (score 2):

On the positive side, if $B$ is finite projective and the sequence splits, then $A$ and $C$ are finite projective as well, because *summands* of finite projective modules are again finite projective. So, in particular, if $B$ and $C$ are finite projective, then $A$ is too (projectivity of $C$ ensures that the sequence splits).

Comment: Along these lines, you could also parody with "If $A$ is injective and $B$ is projective, then $C$ is projective." :)